# How to correctly mention 'Ranked 1st in undergraduate class based on GPA' on CV?

Tags: cv

I recently graduated with the highest GPA in my undergraduate class of 350 students. My current CV reads -

GPA: 3.x/4 (Ranked 1st out of Undergraduate Class of 350 students)

However, this feels slightly forced and awkward. Is there any better way to write this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are all those 350 students having the same major?

Comment: I once saw someone write: "rank in class: 1st out of XXX students" next to the 'summa cum laude' comment. Maybe more appropriate there.

Comment: If you don't want to make it seem overstated, just put a small line for "Class Rank: 1st / 350". Next to "summa cum laude" and GPA, like the other commenter said.

Comment: @scaaahu, yes all 350 have the same major

Comment: Doesn't this make you the valedictorian?

Comment: @HEITZ, it does but the word 'Valedictorian' isn't so commonly used in my country, hence the issue

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if this is applicable in your case, but another way to emphasise that you were at the top of your class is to ask the people writing your recommendations/references to include this piece of information.

Not only does it sound much better coming from someone else (and supposedly that someone is a reliable source), but also recommendations/references are typically the place to brag about such things.

That doesn't mean you shouldn't include it in your C.V. as well, though. Unfortunately, I don't think there is any way to write it so that it doesn't sound (at least a bit) pretentious.

Comment: Sure, I had never thought of it that way! I will ask my professors who write my letters of recommendation to include this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

using both highest GPA and ranked 1st is an overkill because they pretty much say the same thing..id say

GPA : 3.X/4
Rank: 1st in class

I'd use some other place in the CV / professor recommendations to give the class size of 350
if not, itll surely come up in the interview

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have mentioned in my CV under the section called "Educational Details". As the earlier answers suggest, it is preferable to get it mentioned in the recommendation letter.

> **Doctor of Philosophy, Computer Science**
>
> *University of PDAC, Country*
>
> Thesis title: Investigation of ....
>
> **Master of Science, Computer Science**
>
> *University of MSAC, Country*
>
> Thesis title: Bound of the Algorithm 1
>
> GPA: 3.78/4 (Rank: 1/25; Medalist)
>
> **Bachelor of Engineering, Computer Science**
>
> *University of BACK, Country*
>
> GPA: 3.56/4 (Rank: 5/120)